# Trying to increment model attribute - Undefined method on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to increment the value of a column in my model when a link is clicked and i keep getting an undefined method error on the attribute and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong

**model**

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

  def inc_adviser

    self.adviser = self.adviser + 1
    self.save
    redirect_to root_path

  end
end
```

**route**

```
match '/adviser' => 'visitors#inc_adviser'
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to 'Adviser', '/adviser', method: :post  %>
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`self` in that context is the controller instance, not the model instance you seem to expect it to be. You need to get a model instance from somewhere and increment the counter on that:

```
def inc_adviser
  # Something like this, don't have enough information to be more specific.
  model = WhateverModel.find(params[:id])
  model.adviser = model.adviser + 1
  model.save
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

That is, of course, subject to race conditions so you should use [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) instead:

```
def inc_adviser
  WhateverModel.increment_counter(:adviser, params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: yea i've just realised how silly that question was and done something similar to your first suggestion. I think that will work best for me as all i'm trying to do is have aperson tick a box and then the column become true. thanks

Comment: If you want the column to become true then you should say `model.adviser = true` and define your `adviser` column to be a boolean type. Some databases have native booleans, some use C-style zero and one, best to say exactly what you mean to avoid confusion.